# Find out the stored procedure using the table from all databases available

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Please help me on this issue. I have a specific table from a specific database. I want to find the stored procedure using the table from all databases available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I would use [**Aaron Bertrand's improved sp_msforeachdb**](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)

```
EXECUTE sp_foreachdb
   @command = N'SELECT *
                FROM ?.sys.sql_modules AS sm
                WHERE sm.Definition LIKE ''%dbo.YourTable%'''
   , @user_only = 1
```

The `@command` is necessary, but I added the `@user_only` to show that you can skip system databases.  If you do want to check them, remove this parameter.

---

I recommend Aaron's solution over `sp_msforeachdb` because it is unsupported, and as he mentions in his blog, it can miss databases under heavy load.